# How do I solve "ia3" problem on 14.04?

Tags: 14.04

N: Ignoring file 'ia3' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'ia3' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has no filename extension
E: Package 'ia32-libs' has no installation candidate

Answer (score 0):

You probably added a wrong file and a directory to your `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`.

This can be fixed by removing them.

And also there is no package `ia32-libs` in Ubuntu 14.04/

Comment: ia3-libs-raring.list
ia3-libs-raring.list.save........... these are the only "is3" that are in my /etc/apt/sources.list.d/

Comment: How did they get there?  They are wrong. And also there are some other wrong files.

Comment: I will remove them. Thank you for your help in advance